# Ruby on Rails app using Mongo DB: Capybara/Selenium tests using js: fail on second test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, selenium, testing, capybara

I've got an RoR app that uses Mongo DB. The tested functions work correctly in development/production. The test suite used to work. However, ALL tests after the first one now fail.

Specifically, if there's a test using the :js flag:

```
it 'has activity log', :js do
    visit activity_log_site_settings_site_statistics_path
    expect(page).to have_content 'Activity Log'
end
```

the FIRST such test works. However, all subsequent tests with the :js flag fail, because Mongo can't find the record in the database:

```
Problem:
  Document(s) not found for class User with id(s) 59c145db9757d1ce3500000c.
```

The database is populated by driving the app, using FactoryGirl. I'm using DatabaseCleaner between tests (in rails_helper.rb):

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

I've tried:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

and the shared_connection fix: https://gist.github.com/josevalim/470808

Here's an actual test from the suite. The :js flags aren't necessary, I just added them since this was one of the simpler tests:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'SiteStatistics', :vcr do

    before do
        create_xml_feeds
        @site_admin   = FactoryGirl.create :confirmed_user, site_admin: 'true'
        @organization = FactoryGirl.create :organization
        @bulletin     = Bulletin.create(organization: @organization, user: @site_admin, title: 'Test Title', publish_date: '2013-5-12')
        login_user @site_admin
    end

    context 'Activity Log' do

        it 'has activity log', :js do
            visit activity_log_site_settings_site_statistics_path
            expect(page).to have_content 'Activity Log'
        end

        it 'shows created bulletin', :js do
            visit activity_log_site_settings_site_statistics_path
            expect(page).to have_content 'test user created a new bulletin'
            expect(page).to have_content 'Test Organization, Flagstaff, AZ'
        end
    end
end
```

ruby 2.1.0p0, Rails 3.2.22.5

Comment: What version of rails are you using, and did you recently update it?  Also, please show the code where you're creating the expected records.

Comment: Looking at your test, the only thing that jumps out is the `:vcr` metadata - is it possible you recently added/updated your vcr config and it's recording/replaying  your MongoDB interactions, which could then not be returning the document with the newly created user id?  Try disabling VCR and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't do it. I've traced it to Factorygirl. If I create the user using the Factorygirl method it fails, but if I just create it directly it works. Unfortunately, updating the Factorygirl gem didn't do it, so I'm in the process of updating a bunch of gems.